# How to stretch an image horizontally or vertically using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, video-streaming, image-manipulation

I need to fit two video streams on to each other. I need to manipulate one of them so that they fit inside designated four corners of the other video stream. The corners will likely form a trapezoid. Are there OpenCV functions that will allow me to do this? I'm not sure what the best/easiest option would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a trapezoid you need [warpPerspecive](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective) and [getPerspectiveTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform).